# PHP if Statement

Tags: php, mysql

**Hello guys i don't know what is call if or switch statement.**

i have database table field which is call price, so i want to make if the price if the price field empty its show "please Call us for the price " and if the price field is not its i will show what ever i put it..

here is my code but i don't know why its not working..
any body can help please

thanks you

```
<?php 
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles where articlefriendlyURL='%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($aid));
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                     if ($row['price']; = = '') {
                        echo ("Please Call Us for the price");

                        else {
                            echo $row_getArticle['price'];
                        }

                     }
                 }
                 ?>
```

Comment: `if ($row['price'] == '')`

Comment: you also need to take the else outside of the if statement... it is not currently attached so... `}else{//code}//endwhile}`

Comment: Since you are clearly a beginner (no offence), you might want to consider starting to learn a more modern way to connect to mysql than [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). *That extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't separate the equals signs or its no longer a conditional statement to check the equal to. you also had a syntax error with your if/else from the brackets. Try this:

```
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles where articlefriendlyURL='%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($aid));
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (empty($row['price'])) {
            echo ("Please Call Us for the price");
        } else {
            echo $row['price'];
        }
     }
?>
```

Comment: First version of the answer still contained the most obvious syntax error of the question. After modification, there is just code that shows a different solution, without explaining why the solution OP chose wouldn't work (and it *would* work if not for those syntax errors).

Comment: It's _possible_ (although, admittedly quite unlikely) that `0` is a valid price, but your solution would not handle it as such.

Comment: @PatrickQ He never asked it to check for a price of zero so I didn't add it in, there's thousands of other possibilities to make the if/else work incorrectly, so i just went off of what was asked: `if the price field empty`

Comment: I know.  Just sayin'. Plus, as this person is obviously quite new to coding, the difference between the every-day meaning of empty and the functional meaning of PHP's `empty()` may not be as apparent as it is to you and I.

Comment: OP, empty checks for the NULL flag and strings containing no characters. it does not check for malnourished data like a price of 0, 0.00 or $0.00 reference this for more on `empty()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is on

```
if ($row['price']; = = '0')
```

I think the correct syntax of that statement is

```
if ($row['price'] == '0')
```